# Powershell: Write to File -NoNewLine

Tags: powershell, replace, output

I have a bunch of foldernames that I want to write to a file. Using replace. My script looks like this:

```
$file = "C:\Temp\out.txt"
$dirs = gci "C:\Temp\dirs"

foreach ($dir in $dirs){
$d = $dir.Name
(gc $file) -replace "Begin", "Begin`r`n$d" | sc $file
}
```

I want to write the Folders in one Line, separated by commas, after keyword `Begin`. How can I format this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$file = "C:\Temp\out.txt"
$dirs = gci "C:\Temp\dirs" | Where-Object{$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true}

New-Item $file -ItemType "file" -Force
"Begin" | Out-File $file 

$dirs -join "," | Out-File $file -Append
```

You'd probably have to add extension filter in `where-object`, because `PSIsContainer` may evaluate to `true` for archive files.

Comment: thank you. with a little modification -join did the job

Comment: @user2531765 Only now I noticed, that you wanted to write new lines just below "begin", and keep older entries. I'm glad it helped anyway :).